# How to output matrix dimensions together with its content?

Tags: matlab, octave

Is it possible to make GNU Octave to output matrix dimensions together with its content? For example, it should produce smth. like this:

```
octave:1> X = [1 2; 3 4]

X [2x2] =

   1   2
   3   4


octave:2> X(1,:)

ans [1x2] =

   1   2
```

Comment: Are you looking for a setting to flip on? If so, I don't think that there is one. You can certainly do it with a print statement however.

Comment: I am looking for any beautiful solution, if no setting is possible then maybe a simple function will do this?

Comment: Octave is free software. You are free to change the source to do something different if that's what you want. This freedom is probably the biggest advantage of using free software. Can't you use that instead of writing a separate function?

Comment: My guess is that you can change this somewhere inside 'src/pr-output.cc' (or if you're using the development version, inside 'libinterp/corefcn/pr-output.cc').

Comment: @carandraug: that is indeed one of the benefits of free software, you can just change the [source code](http://hg.octave.org/octave/file/tip/libinterp/corefcn/pr-output.cc#l3445) as you see fit :)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In MATLAB, create `display.m` in a folder called `@double` somewhere in your path with this content:

```
function display(v)
name = inputname(1);
if isempty(name)
    name = 'ans';
end
s = num2cell(size(v));
fprintf('\n%s [%d%s] =\n\n', name, s{1}, sprintf('x%d', s{2:end}));
builtin('disp', v);
end
```

This way you override the `display` method for class `double`, and get exactly what you have described. However, this will not work for other classes like `int8`, `logical` or `cell`. You have to override the method for all classes you are interested in. Example:

```
>> A=ones(2,2,2)

A [2x2x2] =

(:,:,1) =
     1     1
     1     1
(:,:,2) =
     1     1
     1     1
```

Comment: I would recommend making a new function like `myDisplay` (overloading builtin functions is not my favorite activity). In that case it will also work on complicated inputs. Try:  `x= {uint8(8);[6 7 8];'abc'}` for example.

Comment: Mohsen, if you really want to be fancy, you should test `get(0,'FormatSpacing')` to see whether MATLAB has `format compact` or `format loose`, and adjust the number of newlines your function displays.

Comment: The newly released R2013b supposedly has a new way to customize the display of objects: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlab.mixin.customdisplayclass.html

Comment: @SamRoberts Thanks for the tip. I actually thought of adding that but decided against that and just replicated the example in the question.

Comment: @Amro My understanding is that it is for user-defined classes and cannot be used for built-in classes like `double`.

Comment: @MohsenNosratinia: I think you are right, it wouldn't work here. I'm still on R2013a, so I cant play with it just yet :)

Comment: Thank you. But your method doesn't work in GNU Octave. Octave shows a warning message however: "warning: function ./display.m shadows a core library function"

Answer (score 8):

While [Mohsen's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18493857/1336150#18760446) does the job indeed, I felt that a separate m-file is somewhat an overkill for this purpose (especially if you don't want to clutter your directory with additional m-files). I suggest using a local anonymous function one-liner instead (let's name it `dispf`), so here are its evolution phases :)

The basic anonymous function I came up with is:

```
dispf = @(x)fprintf('%s =\n\n%s\n', inputname(1), disp(x));
```

which is essentially equivalent to the output in the command window after entering statements (that do not end with a semicolon, of course). Well, almost... because if `inputname` returns an empty string, it doesn't print `'ans'` (and it should). But this can be corrected:

```
dispf = @(x)fprintf('%s=\n\n%s\n', ...
    regexprep([inputname(1), ' '], '^ $', 'ans '), ...
    disp(x));
```

This is basically using `regexprep` to match an empty string and replace it with `'ans'`. Finally, we append the dimensions after the variable name:

```
dispf = @(x)fprintf('%s%s =\n\n%s\n', ...
    regexprep([inputname(1), ' '], '^ $', 'ans '), ...
    strrep(mat2str(size(x)), ' ', 'x'), ...
    disp(x));
```

Now you can plug this one-liner is into any script without the need for an additional m-file!

#### Example

Just a proof that it's working:

```
dispf = @(x)fprintf('%s%s =\n\n%s\n', ...
    regexprep([inputname(1), ' '], '^ $', 'ans '), ...
    strrep(mat2str(size(x)), ' ', 'x'), ...
    disp(x));

A = [1 2; 3 4];
dispf(A)
dispf(A(1, :))
```

The result is as expected:

```
A [2x2] =

   1   2
   3   4

ans [1x2] =

   1   2
```

Answer (score 6):

I don't know if it works in Octave, but in MATLAB you can use `format debug` command and get the dimensions of the array and a bit more:

```
>> format debug
>> X = [1 2; 3 4]

X =


Structure address = 7d19498 
m = 2
n = 2
pr = 373bafa0 
pi = 0
     1     2
     3     4
```

Comment: `size(X)` can also give you matrix dimensions.

Comment: @Fraukje true, but unless you have a trick like Mohsen in his other answer, it is not easy to show a variables `size` next to its name.

Comment: Note that this solution is undocumented (nice find!) and does not work on `x= {uint8(8);[6 7 8];'abc'}` for example.

Comment: FYI, in Octave `format debug` triggers an error (see [example](http://ideone.com/MLlu1o))...

Answer (score 1):

Here is another way to do it. The advantage of this method is that it can deal with more complicated inputs than the mentioned alternatives.

```
function show(s)
t = regexp(s,'=');
if any(t)
    evalin('caller',['disp(size(' s(t+1:end) ')),' s])
else
    evalin('caller',['disp(size(' s ')),' s])
end
```

To use it, save the function and try this:

```
show x = rand(3)
show('y = {uint8(8);[6 7 8]}')
```

Note that it can take the convenient command syntax for simple inputs and that you need the function form with the command in string form for complicated inputs (containing semicolons or apostrophes).

Comment: -1: Putting it in a temporary variable and passing it to a function isn't what the OP has asked for.

Comment: @MohsenNosratinia Thanks, i only tested it on existing variables. My edited version should suit his needs more.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another one. You could either use it to overload `@double/display` as others have explained, or name it something else and use it as your own custom display function:

```
function display(x)
    % determine whether format is loose or compect
    loose = strcmp(get(0,'FormatSpacing'), 'loose');

    % print name or ans
    name = inputname(1);
    if isempty(name), name = 'ans'; end
    if loose, disp(' '); end
    disp([name ' =']);
    if loose, disp(' '); end

    % print size
    sz = size(x);
    if length(sz) == 2
        fprintf('    %s: %d-by-%d\n', class(x), sz(1), sz(2));
    elseif length(sz) == 3
        fprintf('    %s: %d-by-%d-by-%d\n', class(x), sz(1), sz(2), sz(3));
    else
        fprintf('    %s: %d-D\n', class(x), numel(sz));
    end
    if loose, disp(' '); end

    % print array
    disp(x);
end
```

Note that I changed the format of the output a little bit from what you had:

```
>> format compact;
>> x = magic(5);
>> display(x)
x =
    double: 5-by-5
    17    24     1     8    15
    23     5     7    14    16
     4     6    13    20    22
    10    12    19    21     3
    11    18    25     2     9
```