# limit number of values printed to console

Tags: matlab

Matlab's still scrolling as I type this -- I created a 1k x 1k matrix and forgot to append the darn  `;` to the command line.  Isn't there some preference or config command I can use to limit the number of values Matlab prints in the console?  `R`, for example, has such an option.  Matlab reports only the size of long elements of a struct, but I don't see any way to limit the number of doubles returned from a command.

Comment: Check the answer to this question, it might help. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19819544/is-there-a-way-to-automatically-suppress-matlab-from-printing-big-matrices-in-co

Comment: @SamuelNLP  Thanks for the link.  That's one but tugly kludge there, but seeing as Matlab's developers are apparently too (redacted) to put in such an obvious control, I may have to go that route.

Comment: press ctrl+break on the keyboard to stop the program, then correct your program,

Comment: @darenshan not all KBs have a "pause/break" key, and while useful,that doesn't solve the problem of splatter in the console.